# XSLT 1.0 Unique values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have problem with extracting unique values.
And I want to get tree which look like this in HTML.

Main problem is that I don't know how to get distinct values using XSLT 1.0

Pls help :)

```
-Group:AA
    -Category:A
        -InstanceID:1
            --Item:X
        -InstanceID:0
            --Item:X
-Group:BB
    -Category:A
        -InstanceID:1
        -InstanceID:0
    -Category:B
        -InstanceID:0
-Group:CC
    -Category:A
        -InstanceID:1
        -InstanceID:0
    -Category:B
        -InstanceID:0
-Group:DD
    -Category:A
        -InstanceID:1
        -InstanceID:0
    -Category:B
        -InstanceID:0
```

My XML looks like:

```
<Items>
  <Item Name="X" Category="A">
    <Instance>
        <ID> 1 </ID>
        <Group> AA </Group>
    </Instance>
    <Instance>
        <ID> 1 </ID>
        <Group> BB </Group>
    </Instance>
    <Instance>
        <ID> 0 </ID>
        <Group> CC </Group>
    </Instance>
</Item>
<Item Name="X" Category="A">
    <Instance>
        <ID> 1 </ID>
        <Group> AA </Group>
    </Instance>
    <Instance>
        <ID> 0 </ID>
        <Group> DD </Group>
    </Instance>
    <Instance>
        <ID> 1 </ID>
        <Group> CC </Group>
    </Instance>
</Item>
<Item Name="X" Category="B">
    <Instance>
        <ID> 0 </ID>
        <Group> DD </Group>
    </Instance>
    <Instance>
        <ID> 1 </ID>
        <Group> BB </Group>
    </Instance>
    <Instance>
        <ID> 0 </ID>
        <Group> CC </Group>
    </Instance>
</Item>
```

Comment: So i found other way to do this - use key with which concates values -> instance with category and then
template a - for category which call template b
template b - for instance id which call template c
template c - for item's name